# Calculate monthly average

Tags: mysql

I have a table which is recording utilization of a product.

In logistics, there's a parameter called commodity average monthly utilization (CAMU) this keep track of your monthly utilization to date.

here's my table  [tblTransaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16Ba9.png)

desired output would be this
[qry_camu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8pUC.png)

**Explanation:**

prod1 has a total of 102 issuance recorded in 2 months (Feb and Sep) - 102/2 = 51

prod2 has a total of 26 issuance recorded in 2 months (Apr and May) - 26/2 = 13

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Pro Tip: Share table and data in text rather than in images. It would be helpful if you share with `create table` as well as `Insert into` statements

Comment: Hi @James, thank you for your suggestion and will change it appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the table is created with the standard date format for the column `date`.

So the query will be as below

```
select
    commodity,
    sum(issuance)/count(distinct extract(year_month from date)) as CAMU,
    round(sum(issuance)/count(distinct extract(year_month from date)),2) as 'CAMU(rounded)'
from
    tbltransaction
group by 
    commodity;
```

**Output:**

> ```
> commodity |    CAMU | CAMU(rounded)
> :-------- | ------: | ------------:
> prod1     | 51.0000 |         51.00
> prod2     | 13.0000 |         13.00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=75ca3f5e7496984dcc6d73db52cba188)*

Comment: Hi James! Thank you so much for this!